# How to add the toolbar?

Tags: java, android, toolbar

After looking some similar questions I couldn't find why I have the `Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and how to fix it.

First in my `main_activity.java` I imported the two androidx statements as I found on other questions and I added the 2 lines for the toolbar as shown [in point 5](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up):

```java
package com.example.tp01_android;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
...
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Context context = this;
    private ArrayList<String> itemslistArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private EditText newItemTextField;
    private ArrayAdapter simpleAdapter;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ------------------------------- TOOLBAR -------------------------------------------------
        **Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);**
   }
...
```

Now in my `main_activity.xml` I added my toolbar following [the point 4](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="auto"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.389"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Custom list:"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listSimple" />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listSimple"
            android:layout_width="397dp"
            android:layout_height="211dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText">

        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/customListView"
            android:layout_width="408dp"
            android:layout_height="294dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2">

        </ListView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Simple list:" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What did I make wrong or what should I change ?

Comment: if your theme is "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar " then your toolbar will not visible. use "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" instead. or use "        setSupportActionBar(pass_your_toolbar_here);
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Toolbar` import is wrong. Use the `androidx` one instead of support lib version.
In your xml use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

See [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for more info.

The [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up) you pointed hasn't been updated and is using the old support artifacts. Shift to the `androidx.*` version of toolbar as you have done with other components.

Comment: Oh yes sure yes the guide is outdated then, thank you for the input !

Answer (score 1):

Use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in your `main_activity.xml`